# Get date by combination of week day and hours from UTC (javascript or moment)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, momentjs

I have the following data in my db:

```
days : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
selectedDays: 1,2
hours: 23
minutes: 00
```

that in UTC

now I would like to get the real "selected" days for the user itself , means

if my selected day is 0 - Sunday and the time is 23:00, the real user time is Saturday . 01:00 for example

I thought to get the day and time and combine a date from the last week and get a new local time date and from this data to extract the real selected day and real time

how can I do that in moment.js or pure javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the usage of `selectedDays` so i excluded it, but for me this works:

```
const date = {
  days : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
  // selectedDays: 1, 2,
  hours: 23,
  minutes: 00
}
for (const day of date.days) {
  const bar = moment().utc().startOf('week').days(day).hours(date.hours).minutes(date.minutes).toDate();
  console.info(bar, moment(bar).format('dddd HH:mm'));
}
```